# GitHub "Notice for new authentication token formats"

Tags: github, token

I received an email from GitHub indicating my "personal access token, git: https​:​//​github​.​com​/ on «computer-identifier» at «timestamp», has an outdated format...". They give a link, but the page it goes to is very confusing. It has a title "Edit personal access token", at the top it has a warning: "If you’ve lost or forgotten this token, you can regenerate it, but be aware that any scripts or applications using this token will need to be updated.", and then underneath a **lot** of options.

I'm not sure what to do, and what to do afterwards. I was researching this, and the related issues seem to be from the aftermath of interacting with the page where people are not able to access the repositories any more. I need this repository for work, so I don't want to mess anything up. Other people use it too, and I'm not an administrator, so I don't have the option to "try this, or try that". It has to work first time, no guessing.

Is there a guide somewhere for this "Edit personal access token" page?

Comment: Read [https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)